# Revert HTTPS without FTP

Tags: wordpress, ssl, https, ftp

First post, first trouble. I'm currently doing an internship for my school, and I'm working on **Wordpress**. I don't have access to the site's files, because my company hired some freelance years ago who restricted their access to the aspects they needed (Publishing content, moderation, basically that's it).

After what I thought was a good SSL setup, I *changed the website URL to https*, which of course locked me out of the admin. Now I'm only getting **"SSL_ERROR_INTERNAL_ERROR_ALERT"** errors and can't revert the changes.

The solutions I found online basically require me to alter the URL through FTP or Shell Access, *which I don't have*. I think I can get Filezilla to connect, but it gets *kicked out right after the connexion*, meaning I can't access the files.

No one at my company has anything to do with programming or computer stuffs in general, so I'm stuck with the website down. *What should be my next move ?*

Thank you very much !

**EDIT :** Managed to validate the certificate using the domain provider's tool, no need to revert to HTTP anymore, and the site is back on again ! Many thanks to everyone who tried and helped me.

Comment: And this, class, is why you should have SSH access before messing around with your server configuration.

Comment: This poor guy is in trouble, that's for sure.

Comment: Indeed haha ! I'm still a student so I guess that's learning the hard way, but I don't want my employer to have his website down for ages because we made a mistake.

Comment: What was your "SSL setup"?

Comment: Try to launch Chrome in this way: "C:\Program Files (x86)\Google\Chrome\Application\chrome.exe" --ignore-certificate-errors

Comment: Unfortunately it seems like this error can't be ignored/bypassed, or at least *I* can't. The setup was basically done following 'letsencrypt' instructions and using certbot. We then used the 'Really Simple SSL' plugin, seemed ok, so we changed the URL.

Answer (score 0):

If you have database access (like phpMyAdmin), you can change the HTTPS URLs back to HTTP (in the 'wp_options' table).

If you did not have database access, you can add SSL exception in the browser (Firefox screenshot given below) and access WordPress admin panel (with HTTPS) and you can replace the URLs via some plugins like https://wordpress.org/plugins/wp-migrate-db/ (using Find & Replace option).

[image]

Hope this helps.

Comment: Thank you for your answer ! Unfortunately we don't have a database access, so nothing I can do with it. It also seems I can't add an exception for this specific error, that's what I've been trying for the last hours.

Comment: Do you mind sending me the site URL? May be worth trying this - https://support.mozilla.org/en-US/questions/1130471.

Comment: Sure, where could I send it to you ? I'd rather not publish it directly on here ! I tried the solution given in the link but to no avail. Thank you for your help !

Comment: I am too not sure, can you just fill the contact form of our website providing the URL - https://www.outsource-wordpress.com/contact-us/, so I can check?

Comment: Getting an error when submitting the form -> "There was an error trying to send your message. Please try again later." Definitely not my day haha

Comment: Sorry :) I'l check that. There is an email address in that page - can you please directly send the URL to it?

Comment: Done ! Thank you very much for your concern !

Comment: Got the URL and I have tried a lot but it seems you definitely need at least database / FTP access since the site throwing SSL fatal error :(

Comment: Finally got access and managed to validate the certificate 5 minutes ago, now everything's working fine ! Thank you very much again for taking the time to check the site and help me, I really appreciate !